# Remove duplicate in a string

Tags: c#, .net

I am preparing for an interview technical test and I came across this question:

Remove all duplicates in a string without using a buffer, 1 or 2 additional variable is allowed.

I would like to know in doing the following, am I using a buffer? Thanks.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string temp = "amanisaman";
    temp = noDups(temp);
    MessageBox.Show(temp);
}

public string noDups(string word)
{
    string table = "";

    foreach (var character in word)
    {
        if (table.IndexOf(character) == -1)  
        {
            table += character; // would this count as a buffer storage?
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

Comment: Looks more like a C question than a C# one.

Comment: Yes, in my opinion variable table in your example counts as a buffer because it's a temporary variable you are using for storage. Looks like @jalospinoso just solved your question in an elegant way using Linq

Comment: @Serge Why? an C# programmer is not able make this?

Answer (score 5):

Using LINQ...

This assumes your temp string and you want to remove the characters.

```
string originalString = "amanisaman";
string newString = string.Join(" ", originalString.ToCharArray().Distinct());
```

This assumes that you want to remove duplicate words.

```
string originalString = "this is my test string here, this test";
string newString = string.Join(" ", originalString.Split(new Char[] {' '}).Distinct());
```

Comment: Distinct uses `Set<>` (essentially a stripped down, `internal` version of `HashSet<>`) to do its work; I doubt that would satisfy the "no buffer" criterion (unless they meant "no overt buffers"!)

Comment: By the way, there is a [`String.ToCharArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx) overload that takes no arguments: it converts the whole string as you do here.

Comment: If you cast temp into a String object, it's much neater: String.Join("", x.Distinct());

Comment: it works? the arg[0] of string.join cannot be an string empty.

Comment: string originalString = "this is my test string here, this test";
string newString = string.Join(" ", originalString).Split(new Char[] {' '}).Distinct());

Syntex error.

Answer (score 3):

This is because if  exists same char in your string,the index is forever same. 
Try this:

```
 static string noDups(string word)
        {
            string table = "";
            int pos = 0;
            foreach (var character in word.ToCharArray())
            {
                pos = table.IndexOf(character, Math.Abs(pos));
                if (pos == -1)
                {
                    table += character;
                }


            } 
            return table;

        }
```

I think that `.IndexOf` method for this is not idea good. 
You can use `.Contains` method or LINQ.

Using LINQ:

```
 string input = "abahehe";
 string output = new String(input.ToCharArray().Distinct().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of errors in the code you posted (try compiling it!), but the following approach works by creating an extension method to the String class:

```
    static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String temp = ("amanisaman");
        Console.WriteLine(temp.RemoveDupes());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static String RemoveDupes(this String x)
    {
        return String.Join("", x.Distinct());
    }
}
```

Comment: why do make reference to 'this' keyword in function constructor?

Comment: It's called an extension method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) and it makes the function calls really slick. Of course, you can just take the guts of the function out and make it a one liner: String.Join("", temp.Distinct())

Answer (score 1):

Strings in C# are immutable.  Therefore you have to allocate another memory location in some way, which is a buffer, unless you are going to go "unsafe".

This question may actually not be looking for a code answer as much as the correct answer, that in C#, this is not possible unless you go "unsafe".

Answer (score 0):

O(n) solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

 void removeDuplicates(char *);

 void removeDuplicates(char *inp)
{
        int i=0, j=0, FLAG=0, repeat=0;

    while(inp[i]!='\0')
    {
            if(FLAG==1)
            {
                    inp[i-repeat]=inp[i];
            }
            if(j==(j | 1<<(inp[i]-'\0')))
            {
                    repeat++;
                    FLAG=1;
            }
                    j= j | 1<<(inp[i]-'\0');
                    i++;
    }

    inp[i-repeat]='\0';
}

 int main()
{
    char inp[100] = "aaAABCCDdefgccc";
    //char inp[100] = "ccccc";
    //char inp[100] = "\0";
    //char *inp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);

    printf (" INPUT STRING : %s\n", inp);

    removeDuplicates(inp);

    printf (" OUTPUT STRING : %s:\n", inp);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes table is counted as a buffer.

I just want to mention that strings are immutable and any removing (or adding) will cause creation of new string which also could be considered as a buffer.

To minimize extra memory I would do the following:

```
string s = "ababagalamaga";
var h = new HashSet<char>(s);
var b = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char ch in h) {
    b.Append(ch);
}
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Answer (score -2):

"Without using a buffer" is a really bad requirement. What does it mean? Is a new string a buffer? Depending on the interpretation of this requirement, the assignment ranges from very easy to impossible in C#.